# Including source file name on readfile?

Tags: php, path, download, readfile

I have a very simple hide-download-path-script setup like this:

On index.html I have this link:

```
<a href="savefile.php">save</a>
```

On savefile.php I have this bit of code:

```
$file = 'http://www.mysite.com/files/correct_horse_battery_staple.rar';
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
@readfile($file);
```

This does seems to work, but unfortunately it downloads the file as `savefile.php` rather than `correct_horse_battery_staple.rar`.

Is there any way to change not only the file name but also the extension?

Comment: Try [`header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="correct_horse_battery_staple.rar"');`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#example-4365). If your filename includes non-ASCII characters, getting it to show across browsers will be more complicated. (Edit: also, use a local path to the file instead of an `http://`-based one.)

Answer (score 2):

I have had same problem

Solved as below:

```
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");


header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');


readfile($filename);
```

I hope it help u

Answer (score 0):

Your link goes to savefile.php, and the browser never got another filename than savefile.php.
You need to add a header like:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="correct_horse_battery_staple.rar"');
```

or better...

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
```

Hope it helps!